# IONIC: Like dislike functionality within `ng-repeat`

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic framework.Currently i am working on ionic iOS app.  I need to do like dislike functionality. As i have multiple records coming from web service  and for each record i have to put functionality of  like,dislike and comment with total count and saved these information into `database`.

Also change `CSS` for like and dislike button.

I do not understand how to establish this function into my app.Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach:

```js
angular.module('main',[]).controller('mainController', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.items = [
    {"id":1,"title": "item1", "like": false},
    {"id":2,"title": "item2", "like": true},
    {"id":3,"title": "item3", "like": false},
    {"id":4,"title": "item4", "like": true},
    {"id":5,"title": "item5", "like": false},
    {"id":6,"title": "item6", "like": true},
    {"id":7,"title": "item7", "like": false},
    {"id":8,"title": "item8", "like": false},
    {"id":9,"title": "item9", "like": true},
    {"id":10,"title": "item10", "like": false},
    
  
  ];
  
  $scope.toggle_like = function(item){
      
      //send item.id to HTTP Call to change id in DB and execute following statement in success callback
      item.like = !item.like;
  
  }

})
```

```css
.fake_link:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainController">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th> Title </th>
    <th> Like </th>
  
  </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td> {{item.title}} </td>
    <td ng-click="toggle_like(item)" class="fake_link"> <span ng-if="item.like"> Unlike </span> <span ng-if="!item.like"> Like </span> </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lxwbeeat/

Comment: Thank you so much @user3597009  i'll try and let you know  :)

Comment: I have tried this its working fine,  but i also want to change count increase or decrease by like and dislike.

Comment: you can use underscore.js for that or simply you can count likes with code like:
(edit toggle_like function)
function toggle_like(item){
item.like = !item.like;
$scope.liked = $scope.items.filter(function(item){return item.like;}).length;
// and disliked are always $scope.items.length - $scope.liked;
}